# How add subitems with array

Tags: android, listview, subitem

I want to make a simple application that contains a listview and underneath a subitem to say something more than that button.

In this case big say "Hi" and "Sub Hi" in subitem.

I have read in places that you have to create a separate class but the codes that are difficult to get.

Is there a simple example where you can just walk array (as in my code) for each array, and then combine them to tell you the item?

i want something like this: ( do it with paint)

[image]

```
final String[] test={"Hi"};
    String[] subtest={"Sub HI"};

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LV_lista);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prueba);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subprueba);



    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

            String NombreHabilidad = prueba[position];

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "u click "+ NombreHabilidad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    });
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ? something like listview with headers ?

Comment: No, a simple listview with name and subitem as shown in the examples of listview that says "item 1" big and bottom "sub item 1" but with the words that I want

Comment: check the examples again and trace where they get the adapter data from and change that to what you need.

Comment: i only find the hards examples :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ExpandableListView.

Try [this tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/).

Comment: I think you missed my point, do not want to create groups simply want to create a listview that displays various information

Comment: If you want each item of your ListView to contain various information, you need to create a custom xml layout for the item and a custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @CristianCV it should not be hard thing to do, lots of examples on the internet and even the samples you been looking at explains it really well, just take time and look at the code in the samples